# Adding new property to object of arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have policyNumbers array, and I want to add it to current each policy.
Problem is that for each object it's adding every policy number. I just need for one policy one number,
I have 3 policies and 3 policy numbers.

Each object must have only one policy number, how can I fix this?

```
      const travelersInfoWithPolicyNumbers = payload.travelersInfo.map((traveler) => ({
        ...traveler,
        policyNumber: generatedPolicyNumbers.map(
          (policyNumber: { policyNumber: string }) => policyNumber.policyNumber
        ),
      }))
```

I expected

```
[
    {
        firstName: 'test',
        lastName: 'test',
        age: 30
        policyNumber: "TRB200",
       }
       {
        firstName: 'test1',
        lastName: 'test1',
        age: 35
        policyNumber: "TRB201",
       }
    {
     firstName: 'test2',
     lastName: 'test2',
     age: 50
     policyNumber: "TRB202",
    }
  ]
```

But I get

```
[
    {
        firstName: 'test',
        lastName: 'test',
        age: 30
        policyNumber: [
            "TRB200",
            "TRB201",
            "TRB202"
          ]
       }
       {
        firstName: 'test1',
        lastName: 'test1',
        age: 35
        policyNumber: [
            "TRB200",
            "TRB201",
            "TRB202"
          ]
       }
    {
     firstName: 'test2',
     lastName: 'test2',
     age: 50
     policyNumber: [
        "TRB200",
        "TRB201",
        "TRB202"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

generatedPolicyNumbers data:

```
[
  {
    "policyNumber": "TRB200"
  },
  {
    "policyNumber": "TRB201"
  },
  {
    "policyNumber": "TRB202"
  }
]
```

payload.travelersInfo data:

```
[
    {
        firstName: 'test',
        lastName: 'test',
        age: 30
       }
       {
        firstName: 'test1',
        lastName: 'test1',
        age: 35
       }
    {
     firstName: 'test2',
     lastName: 'test2',
     age: 50
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Please provide you input data, in this case it would be payload.travelersInfo and generatedPolicyNumbers

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added data.

Comment: Ok, so you have independent 2 arrays of data which you want to combine basically. The question here to understand, how exactly you should know that Policy "TRB200" should belong to Traveler "test"? Is it just by index in array?

Comment: If travalersInfo length is 3 there always will be 3 policy numbers. It doesn't matter which one it belongs to. It is important for all 3 travelers must have policy numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments, the solution would be something like this.

```
  const travelersInfoWithPolicyNumbers = payload.travelersInfo.map((traveler,index) => ({
    ...traveler,
    policyNumber: generatedPolicyNumbers[index].policyNumber,
  }))
```